# LateX: text going smaller and smaller

Tags: fontsize

I guess this is an unusual question as I have not found anything related (then again, maybe I searched poorly).

So what I would like to do is having an enumeration (in a beamer slide) go smaller and smaller in size, as smoothly as possible.

Currently, I haven't found a better solution than the following:

```
{\small my text is going smaller and }
{\footnotesize smaller and smaller and}
{\scriptsize smaller and smaller and }
{\tiny smaller and smaller and ...}
```

However I don't like it so much as it really looks like "blocks" of words in the enumeration and there is nothing smooth about it. (note that line skipping here does not imply line skipping in the rendering)

Any idea to get a better disappearing effect? Maybe a package I'm unaware of that provides more flexibility with fontsize?

Comment: Just a precision: by "enumeration", I actually just mean a sequence of words, not an environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\vanish#1{{\dimen@15pt\par\lineskip\p@\baselineskip\z@\@xvanish#1 * }}
\def\@xvanish#1 {%
  \ifx*#1\par\else
    {\fontsize{\dimen@}\z@\selectfont#1 }\dimen@.97\dimen@\expandafter\@xvanish
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\vanish{my text is going smaller and 
smaller and smaller and
smaller and smaller and 
smaller and smaller and 
smaller and smaller and 
smaller and smaller and \ldots} %

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And we vanish when you come `;-)` +1

Comment: Sorry for not thanking you earlier, it's been a while but your solution is really great! Thanks!!